# ElasticSearch Search for specified value within `FromX` and `ToY` fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to query by specified value within range that made by value of two `FromX` and `ToY` fields, and search `Title` as `text` field by `query_string` query.

This example shows my goal:

```
Id | FromX | ToY | Title
-----------------------------
 1 |   1   |  7  |  Mohammad
 2 |   2   |  3  |  Ali
 3 |   1   |  6  |  MohammadAli
 4 |   2   |  5  |  MohammadReza
 5 |   1   |  2  |  AliReza
 6 |   2   |  2  |  Sayed Ali
```

example query:

```
value: 2 AND title: *Ali*
```

result for query:

```
Id | FromX | ToY | Title
-----------------------------
 2 |   2   |  3  |  Ali
 3 |   1   |  6  |  MohammadAli
 5 |   1   |  2  |  AliReza
 6 |   2   |  2  |  Sayed Ali
```

**Update 1:**

- Add last record with `Id=6` in the sample data and result.

Comment: How is your `Title` field analyzed?

Comment: Not set any analyzer yet.

Comment: `Title` field contains `Persian language` content. 
Can you help me about analyze on it?

Comment: That would better belong into another question since it's a different issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should give you what you expect:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "FromX": {
              "lte": 2
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "ToY": {
              "gte": 2
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*ali*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However, not that prefix wildcards should be avoided at all cost as they will penalize the performance of your query. You should probably analyze your title field using ngrams and do normal match queries on the `Title` field, instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, `ToX` must be `ToY` I can't edit your reply.
I write query like you but return results just `FromX=2` and `ToY=2` !

Comment: I update question and sample data also.

I write query like you but return results just `FromX=2` and `ToY=2` like record `Id=6` that update in question and sample data.

I need that the query must support range between FromX and ToY completely.

Comment: Are you sure ? I get 4 results, i.e. 2, 3, 5, 6. Please try again

Comment: Yeesss :) 
Your answer is correct.
Problem in my query was in `gte in FromX` and `lte in ToY`.
Thank you